# SyntaxError: invalid syntax (connections.py, line 36) when running python manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm on Windows 7, i have Mysql 5.5 installed after a lot of problems and python 3.3 and django 1.5.1, i created the db in mysql and when i run `python manage.py syncdb` for the first time i get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax (connections.py, line 36)`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'test_django',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

of course the password and db name are correct. Any ideas?

EDIT - connections.py is in the mysqldb module, on line 36 there is

```
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
```

How can i see the traceback?

Comment: @Wooble of what file?I haven't touched django standard install and i couldn't find the file connections.py in the django folder. I'm following the tutorial here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: connections.py, presumably.

Comment: @Wooble ok connections.py is in the MySQLdb extension... on line 35 there is 
del connection

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Do you get a traceback printed with the error message?

Comment: @Wooble im using python 3.3 and i see no traceback

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to use a Python 2 MySQLdb library with Py3K. (The syntax of `raise` changed in Py3K)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the latest version of Django, 1.5, which is the first that is compatible with Python 3. Earlier Django versions are only compatible with Python 2.x.

Comment: No i'm using 1.5.1, sorry i didn't specify that

Comment: Have you an idea of why i'm not seeing a traceback?It seems that an exception is raised on line 36 but there is no traceback

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Line 36 syntax error and solved it
It was the mismatch of Mysql driver with Python 3 that causes this
http://bunwich.blogspot.com/2014/02/finally-mysql-connector-that-works-with.html can help with this

Also :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'secretpassword',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Note the ENGINE is `mysql.connector.django` and not `django.db.backends.mysql`.